# Checking row by row if a value is of the type int in a dataframe and selecting incorrect rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

I have the following data frame (just a subset):

|  | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 66 |
| 1 | 91 |

I want to check row by row to validate if values under time column are of type int. If they are not, then save that incorrect row in a new data frame.
I have spent days but cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [66, '91']})
new_df = df[(df['Time'].map(type) != int)]

    Time
1   91
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Pandas function [`pd.api.types.is_integer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_integer.html) to test for integer type, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [66, '91', 1.23, 'a', 0.0, '', np.nan, 77]})

non_int_df = df[~df['Time'].map(pd.api.types.is_integer)]

print(non_int_df)


   Time
1    91
2  1.23
3     a
4   0.0
5      
6   NaN
```